# TSQL: Is it possible to modify the the value of an PK-Identity?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let say I have this table

```
 Id(PK)     Country         Capital City
+--------+---------------+------------------+
+   1    +    USA        + Washington, D.C. +
+--------+---------------+------------------+
+   2    +   Japan       +  Tokyo           +
+--------+---------------+------------------+
```

What if I want to insert `France-Paris`. But I want that row to have Id = 1, USA Id = 2, then Japan Id = 3?

Is there a way to do that using SQL? What I'm about to do is to generate a Script where I'll do that manually. However, if there is a different way, I'd like to apply it.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Why is the value of the PK in this example so important besides being used to uniquely identify a row. And how would you deal with FK constraints?

Comment: Because I am reconstructing a table that used to exists. In normal situation, I wouldn't even worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it isn't pretty if you get your values wrong. Use [`IDENTITY_INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Country ON
--Do your manipulation here.
INSERT INTO dbo.County(Id, country, [Capital City]) SELECT 1, 'France', 'Paris'
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Country OFF
```

**BUT**: You have an identity and a primary key and you need to shuffle values about so you would need to drop the ID column and re-create it since you cannot update an `IDENTITY` column. Given you may have other tables relying on this, this is likely to be more trouble than it's worth. If you're really desperate to have France at position 1 you will have to do quite a bit of work to disable FKs then copy the ID column to a new column, insert your value where you want it, make sure the numbers are sequential and finally re-create the identity and primary key and re-enable foreign keys.

As a side note, try and avoid spaces in object names.

Comment: Actually a separate unique Order field - that is not the identity - can be used to impose a sort order, without having the cascading and key invalidation issues that will come and hunt the application layer.

Comment: Yes very true, although the OP seems curiously set on changing the pk values.